# Display a word Doc with visualforce page

Tags: ms-word, editor, salesforce, visualforce

I want to know what can i do to display the content of a word document, that is in an "**attachment**" or a "**content**", in a visualforce page. I not only need to see the text but also have the ability to edit it.

Comment: Can't do ;) At least - not without some ActiveX craziness that will work in IE only. I did something like that in the past and... never again. Ask the users to download, edit & upload back. Tell them about Mail Merge and the force the SF support to enable "Extended Mail Merge" for your org. But don't decide to make Word docs editable online, "here be dragons" ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible without ActiveX. The only possible solution is to have them edit and upload back. Here is something I would implement:

**1. Use documents instead of attachments/Content 

2. Create a VF page to display the shared documents/own documents (hyperlink in VF to the doc. record) 

3. Create a link to document to view/edit it. (Custom Apex Dev.) 
 
i.e. Using Page Reference, redirect them to '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=IDofthedocument'**

I think this should be good enough to not to show the main documents tab (if you dont want the users messing around with the data) and get the functionality working.

***I can post the code if required. Please let me know if this helps!***